# How can I "Refactor => introduce a variable" inside an ascx\Eval code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, eval, ascx

I have some code which is too complex

```
visible='<%#((String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("IDLingua").ToString()) [...]%>' runat="server">
```

And I'd like to introduce a variable to hold the result of the String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("IDLingua").ToString() operation.

I can do it both on the Ascx code or in the code behind. But after some hours of research I still don't understand clearly how to do it

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign such an object to simple variable.

```
visible='<%#((String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("IDLingua").ToString())
[...]%>' runat="server">
```

In general, I would not recommend processing data on aspx view. In my opinion it would be better if you process it in code behind or even earlier (between fetching data from database and preparing view in code behind). View should be minimal and only present data, not process it.

Anyway... I guess your code with Eval exists inside a repeater or another control using data binder.

You should be able to define additional hidden field control and save the expression there.

```
<asp:HiddenField id="hidTmp" runat="server" value='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("IDLingua").ToString() %>' />
```

But remember it would work only inside `<ItemTemplate>` tags. You could use hidTmp as variable then.

Another approach could be using `OnItemDataBound` method and using code behind (where introducing variable is not a problem):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This looks like logic that should be out of the UI. You could add a new property to your object IsVisible that contains the logic

```
visible='<%#Eval("IsVisible")%>' runat="server">
```

Or create a function in the code behind and call it

```
visible='<%#IsVisible(Eval("IDLingua"))%>' runat="server">
```

Comment: It's already a nice solution but can I access IDLingua directly from code behind? I want to separate as much as possible the View from the Controller. And if the code behind could see the IDLingua I would have solved.

Comment: @Revious in the 2nd example, IDLingua is passed as a parameter, the function doesn't need to know where the value comes from. In the first example, the class takes care of all the logic, so only the class knows about IDLingua.

Comment: but how do I access the IDLingua from the code behind? (all the code I posted is inside a repeater)